# What does (SAS) Enterprise Miner's "Bucket Transformation" do?

Tags: data-transformation, python, sas

In SAS's Enterprise Miner there is a "Bucket Transformation" which from what I can tell, is a term that is unique to Enterprise Miner.  It takes a continuous variable and groups it to become an ordinal variable with a certain number of bins.  I would like to know what it is doing and what this would be called in other software.  I am attempting to do something like this in python but I am not sure how to make "optimal buckets".

Comment: http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug07/sa/sa17.pdf

Comment: @statsnewb, the paper referenced above by Max gives you a clear definition for what bucket transformation does. SAS support is very helpful, you might want to contact them or you could consult their documentation which is exhaustive.

Comment: The SAS documentation is exhaustive.  However, from what I can tell, the Enterprise Miner documentation is not.  @Max thank you.  I am interested to see how they pick the optimal number of "buckets", any ideas on how they do this?

Comment: What this is often called in other software is bad statistical practice.

Comment: @FrankHarrell what do you mean by that?

Comment: Binning categorical predictors creates artificial discontinuities and worsens the fit.  It is also arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer what SAS's Bucket Transformation does. You'll have to read the documentation. You *might* want to have a look at `pandas.cut` or `pandas.qcut` though.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.cut.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.qcut.html

Answer (score 2):

This question is old. If you are still interested, bucket transformation is called equal spaced bucket. If you have continuous variable with min=1 and max=100, for example, buckets=10. Then the transformation creates buckets by 1-10, 10-20,20-30... 90-100, regardless how many observations fall into each bucket. Eventually, (max-min) for each bucket is the same. Hope this helps. 
Jason Xin

Answer (score 0):

'Buckets' or 'bins' are used to transform a continuous variable into groups. For example, a model I am building might benefit by ranking subjects according to income level.

0 - $19,999k
$20k - $39,999k
.....
$100k and above

Creating buckets will allow me to do this.

-- Glenn